# Python input formatting

Tags: python, list, format

I am trying to get my input look like this, but i dont know how should i format it:

```
Enter the rainfall for January:  1
Enter the rainfall for February: 2
Enter the rainfall for March:    3
```

This is the inputt i get:

```
Enter the rainfall for January: 1
Enter the rainfall for February: 2
Enter the rainfall for March: 3
```

Here is my code:

```
def main():
months=("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
values=[0]*12

for n in range(len(values)):
    print("Enter the rainfall for", (months[n]), end=": ")
    values[n]=float(input())

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the print statement as

```
print("Enter the rainfall for", '{0:11s}'.format(months[n]+':'), end="")
```

Output

```
Enter the rainfall for January:   1
Enter the rainfall for February:  2
Enter the rainfall for March:     3
Enter the rainfall for April:     4
Enter the rainfall for May:       5
Enter the rainfall for June:      6
Enter the rainfall for July:      7
Enter the rainfall for August:    8
Enter the rainfall for September: 9
Enter the rainfall for October:   0
Enter the rainfall for November:  1
Enter the rainfall for December:  2
```

Comment: Just to be clear here, it works since we know the lengths of all the months. In a general case, we'll find the max length of the strings and then perform the padding using something like s.ljust(max_len).

Answer (score 0):

You can also save some typing by using the existing [calendar module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/calendar.html)

```
from calendar import month_name
def main():
    values = []
    for month in month_name[1:]:
        values.append(float(input('Enter the rainfall for {0:11s}'.format(month + ':'))))
```